# WEP Cracking with airmon-ng using only monitor mode

Tags: aircrack-ng

DISCLAIMER: This router is mine, and this is purely for educational reasons, so please do not close this question.

I have `aircrack-ng` installed on my Ubuntu laptop.  My wireless card drivers do not support packet injection, and I am trying to crack a WEP key using only monitor mode. However, I can't find a tutorial (I had one, but then I lost the link).

What is the syntax to listen to, save, and crack monitored packets?

Comment: That is very ambiguous - "if it's possible, it's all over google".  It's possible, but it's not all over.  All the tutorials seem to talk about using packet injection.

Comment: What do you mean?  I just don't know what to do.  I can start wlan0 to get a mon0 interface, but I don't know what commands to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like there are some guides that have been posted since I last checked.  In particular, [this one](http://www.soldierx.com/tutorials/Cracking-WEP-aircrack-ng-suite) is very helpful.

Basically, general procedure is to:

1. Initialize your wireless adapter with `airmon-ng start <wireless adapter>`.  This 
   will sometimes give you a different name to use from now on (e.g. `wlan0` turns into 
   `mon0`.)
2. Run `airodump-ng <adapter name>`. Once you've identified the
   AP, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end the process.
3. Run `airodump-ng -w file-to-save-to --channel <AP's channel> --bssid
   <bssid or MAC address of target> <interface>`.

To actually process this data, run `aircrack-ng filename.cap`.  This will begin one crack attempt at execution, and if it does not succeed will try again at regular intervals.  (This can be done at the same time as the other commands are being done in another tab.)

Comment: Sorry for the cluttered-looking post, but I didn't want to just link-and-leave.  This will be marked as the answer once the 2 days wait for accept is up =P

Comment: Even though this may or may not contain pack-injection instructions, the command sequence still works on a wireless card without patched drivers.  It only works when there are others connected to and using the network, not when you're the only one connected.

Answer (score 1):

WindowsEscapist's instructions are correct, except they include the the sections for packet injection.

> Basically, general procedure is to:
>
> 1. Initialize your wireless adapter with airmon-ng start . This will sometimes give you a different name to use from
>      now on (e.g. wlan0 turns into mon0.)
> 2. Run airodump-ng . Once you've identified the AP, Ctrl+C
>      to end the process.
> 3. Run airodump-ng -w file-to-save-to --channel  --bssid
>       .

the commands that contains `aireplay` are used for injection attacks on the router.

Comment: It worked without a hitch for me, even though I don't have drivers with packet injection.

Comment: By that, I mean that running the packet injection test fails.

Comment: Instead of copying and pasting (parts of) my answer, you might want to suggest an edit or edit my post yourself (with an explanation in comments).  That's how SU works! (Plus, that way you get my formatting.)